# Php ide in java shows a line in the middle of the code window

Tags: netbeans

I'm using phpstorm and netbeans and everytime i want to edit a php file there is a line in the middle of the code window.
it happens also in the options menu where there is a preview of the code.
I have windows 7 64bit and i installed the latest java.
both phpstorm and netbeans use java to run and thats why i presume that the
java needs to be repaired some how.
Has anyone every encountered this issue?
Thanks

[Screenshot at this link](http://bit.ly/fFDKvk)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line is to show you where 80 chars is.   There's [a good explanation on the netbeans forum here](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic11829.html):

> It's there as a guide to line length.
>
> Good style generally avoids lines
>   longer than 80 characters,  and only
>   70 characters for examples intended to
>   be used in  documentation.
>
> The red line simply marks 80
>   characters wide (by default) and is a 
>   visual guide to break long expressions
>   over multiple lines.
>
> You can adjust the placement of the
>   red line in (Netbeans 6.7):  Tools >
>   Options > Editor > Formatting.
>
> On the left you'll see Right Margin,
>   with a default value of 80.
>
> If you want to remove the red line all
>   together, you can either:
>
> 1. Increase the margin value to 160 or more; or goto
> 2. Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors, change the color of the Text Limit
>      Line to white
>
> There may be other ways, but these are
>   the easiest ways I know of.
>
> The Java Code Conventions can be found
>   here  (and clause 4.1 is on page 9 of
>   the pdf):
>
> http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/CodeConventions.pdf

Comment: To add onto what Colin said, you can goto Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting and set the right margin to zero. For reference, I'm using netbeans 8.1 in linux